# Why do さ and ざ look the same except for the little strokes on the side?

Tags: hiragana

I am learning hiragana and I am looking at sa, shi, su, se, so, and za, ji, zu, ze, zo. The characters look the same except the "z" characters have little strokes on the side of the character. Why is this? And what is the difference? When do we use it, and how?

Example:

さ vs  ざ

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're confused about? さ _sa_ and ざ _za_ are two different hiragana syllables. The reason that they look similar except for the ゛ is because the ゛ is what is called a _dakuten_ or "voicing mark", and is mostly used to show that a syllable is [voiced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(phonetics)). You don't really need to know what voicing is, though; just know that さ is pronounced _sa_ and ざ is pronounced _za_.

Comment: This is like asking why `a` and `ä` or `å` look similar. They are different letters, but come from the same letter `a`.

Comment: @senshin:  [Comments are not for answers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).

Comment: What does "voiced" mean? Is it just.. for example I want to spell strawberry イチゴ
it has "dakuten." symbol in it. Is it just another syllable in the hiragana? it looks like "so" but with the dakuten symbol. so it is its own symbol? "ga"

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the similarity is that they are thought of as being *variants of the same letter*. The little dots are called 濁点｛だくてん｝, and they designate that you should say the same sound but voiced instead of unvoiced.

The sounds S, T, and K are always spoken with a burst of air, while the voice box is silent. When these sounds are "voiced," that is if your voice is making a noise at the same time as you speak these sounds, they become Z, D, and G instead. Rather than make entirely new kana columns for the voiced variants of these sounds, the 濁点 are used.

The one column where the rule might seem a little strange to English ears is the は・ば・ぱ group. In this case, I would consider ぱ to be unvoiced, ば to be the voiced version, and は to be a different consonant altogether. This one you just need to memorize.

Comment: What does "voiced" mean? Is it just.. for example I want to spell strawberry イチゴ it has "dakuten." symbol in it. Is it just another syllable in the hiragana? it looks like "so" but with the dakuten symbol. so it is its own symbol? "ga"

Comment: @Okue Have you learned about katakana yet? イチゴ is i-chi-go in katakana. ゴ has a _dakuten_ because it is pronounced _go_, and /g/ is the voiced version of /k/ (without the _dakuten_, you have コ, which is _ko_). It should not resemble _so_, which is written そ (hiragana) or ソ (katakana).

Comment: You won't find h/b/p strange if you know the historical evolution.

Comment: I don't know the evolution, and would like to. Of course it seems natural to the Japanese, or they wouldn't have done it. That's why I specified "to English ears".